# Zurb Foundation 5 hiding content in Offcanvas

Tags: zurb-foundation

If you copy and paste Zurb's "Basic" code implementation of Foundation's Offcanvas layout, the paragraph content doesn't scroll. Doesn't this defeat the utility of this functionality? What am I missing here?

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/offcanvas.html

This is the code I'm copy-pasting from that page:

```
<div class="off-canvas-wrap">
  <div class="inner-wrap">

    <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle" >Menu</a> 

    <!-- Off Canvas Menu -->
    <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
        <!-- whatever you want goes here -->
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        ...
        </ul>
    </aside>

    <!-- main content goes here -->
    <p>THESE PARAGRAPHS WILL NOT SCROLL Set in the year 0 F.E. ("Foundation Era"), The Psychohistorians opens on Trantor, the capital of the 12,000-year-old Galactic Empire. Though the empire appears stable and powerful, it is slowly decaying in ways that parallel the decline of the Western Roman Empire. Hari Seldon, a mathematician and psychologist, has developed psychohistory, a new field of science and psychology that equates all possibilities in large societies to mathematics, allowing for the prediction of future events.</p>
    <p>THESE PARAGRAPHS WILL NOT SCROLL Set in the year 0 F.E. ("Foundation Era"), The Psychohistorians opens on Trantor, the capital of the 12,000-year-old Galactic Empire. Though the empire appears stable and powerful, it is slowly decaying in ways that parallel the decline of the Western Roman Empire. Hari Seldon, a mathematician and psychologist, has developed psychohistory, a new field of science and psychology that equates all possibilities in large societies to mathematics, allowing for the prediction of future events.</p>
    <p>THESE PARAGRAPHS WILL NOT SCROLL Set in the year 0 F.E. ("Foundation Era"), The Psychohistorians opens on Trantor, the capital of the 12,000-year-old Galactic Empire. Though the empire appears stable and powerful, it is slowly decaying in ways that parallel the decline of the Western Roman Empire. Hari Seldon, a mathematician and psychologist, has developed psychohistory, a new field of science and psychology that equates all possibilities in large societies to mathematics, allowing for the prediction of future events.</p>

  <!-- close the off-canvas menu -->
  <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include javascript files :

In the head section

```
     <script src="/js/vendor/custom.modernizr.js"></script>
```

Just before the closing body tag

```
    <script src="/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/vendor/fastclick.js"></script>

    <script src="/js/foundation.js"></script>
```

and  the right dependency, in your case add this:

```
    <script src="/js/foundation.offcanvas.js"></script>
```

for more details go to : http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html

regards